# Is there a OneDrive “Failed to Upload” report somewhere?

Tags: onedrive

I have 700+Gb free capacity on my OneDrive account and yesterday was uploading a nested set of folders and files total approximately 75Gb.

During the upload I noticed a couple of files tagged as “unable to upload” — they were regular JPEG files so I assumed momentary glitch and resolved to reload at the end of the session, which I left running overnight. This morning the upload has completed, but the “failed to upload” list has disappeared, so I have no idea what files I now need to reload.

Is there any way to get a report of the failed to upload files?